# Seleccionar registros en base a dos valores distintos para un mismo campo

Tags: mysql-workbench

Tengo esta tabla y quiero  que me seleccione los lotes siempre y cuando tengan inicio y fin, no solo alguna de las dos.

Traté con un `and` pero no se me selecciona nada ya que creo que  con esa sentencia  espera a que un solo campo cumpla con los dos criterios:

```
select Lote From hen.lote where Etapa ='Inicio' and 'Fin'

select Lote From hen.lote where Etapa ='Inicio' and Etapa='Fin';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido @rolyx22. Por favor, incluye la estructura de tu tabla, así como la consulta actual que estás realizando, para que podamos ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la sentencia que estás usando? ¿Qué resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: select Lote From hen.lote where Etapa ='Inicio' and 'Fin';

Comment: tambien use esta        select Lote From hen.lote where Etapa ='Inicio' and Etapa='Fin';

Comment: Coloca las sentencias en tu pregunta, por favor, puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta ;)

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta :)  La primera sentencia debiera arrojarte error, si mal no entiendo, ya que después del `AND` no comparas nada, sólo colocas el valor "Fin". La segunda sentencia es como dices: no te devuelve nada porque la estás comparando con distintos valores. Si es por eso, puedes usar una comparación `IN`, pero para tu caso específico, tampoco serviría, creo yo...

Comment: si de echo tambien trate con un In pero me trai todos los datos de regreso

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que tu modelo de datos está bien diseñado? Yo veo demasiados datos redundantes...

Comment: que es lo que se te hace redundante ?

Comment: practicamente todas las columnas tienen el mismo valor, independientemente de si es *inicio* o *fin*. Puede cambiar IDH, ORDEN, Operador o Reactor para un mismo lote en caso inicio o fin? Si no es asi, entonces las horas de inicio y fin deberian ser columnas, o ser extraidas a otra tabla para evitar repetir todo el registro.

Comment: @Klaimmore Pues sí, eso sería lo ideal. ¿Será que rolyx22 tendrá permiso para alterar la tabla (y el sistema)?

Answer (score 2):

Con esta consulta, haces que los valores de "Inicio" y "Fin" te aparezcan hacia el lado, como columnas, y así puedes averiguar cuáles tienen o no sus respectivas etapas registradas:

```
SELECT L.lote, Inicio, Fin
FROM lote L
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT lote, etapa AS Inicio FROM lote WHERE etapa = 'Inicio') ini ON L.lote = ini.lote
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT lote, etapa AS Fin FROM lote WHERE etapa = 'Fin') fin ON L.lote = fin.lote
GROUP BY L.lote
```

El resultado de esto es algo como:

```
lote    Inicio  Fin
------------------------
t-001   Inicio  Fin
t-002   Inicio  (null)
```

Esto lo probé en [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/219c0f/3).

Ya jugando con la misma consulta, puedes hacer los `where` que necesites, y de hecho manipular el valor de las "columnas" Inicio y Fin (en mi ejemplo, salen los valores reales que trae la columna "etapa", pero tú por ejemplo, podrías darle un 1, como para que sea más "booleano", etc. :p ).

Answer (score 1):

Si los lotes pueden tener una sola entrada y salida, puedes utilizar este query:

```
SELECT Lote
FROM hen.lote
GROUP BY Lote
HAVING COUNT(Lote) > 1;
```